# Pandas group by rolling sum

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby

I have a data that looks like below

```
id  var window
1   0   3
1   0   3
1   9   3
1   1   3
1   0   3
1   10  5
1   0   12
2   0   12
2   3   4
2   0   12
2   5   12
```

What I'd like to do is calculating rolling sum groupby "id" conditional on the value of "var". If "var" is non-zero, rolling sum is calculated, the length of rolling window is taken from column "window"; if "var" is zero, rolling sum equals 0.

Below is the desired results

```
   id   var window  roll_sum
    1   0   3       0
    1   0   3       0
    1   9   3       9
    1   1   3       10
    1   0   3       0
    1   10  5       20
    1   0   12      0
    2   0   12      0
    2   3   4       3
    2   0   12      0 
    2   5   12      8
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why is the `roll_sum` for row `-3` indicated as `3` when the window length is `4`?

Comment: @a_guest because I want to calculate roll_sum by "id". Even though the window length is 4, roll_sum will only sum up the first two rows of id = 2.